# How to change Angular2 Material fab speed dial animation as in angular1

Tags: angular

I have Angular2 Material Fab Speed Dial, I need to do animation for that Angular2 in this format as in link [Angular1 link](http://tutorialsplane.com/runtest/try.php?trycode=angular-material-fab-speed-dial&post_code=code6&). This is Angular1 animation part. Please suggest me to do same way in Angular2.

In the above link I need my code to work like md-scale Example.

I am here by sharing HTML code Angular2:

```
<div id="right-side" class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-sm-1 col-xs-1" layout="column">
  <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" aria-label="New Task" (click)='FabToggle = !FabToggle'>
    <md-icon style="color:white;">menu</md-icon>
  </button>
  <div class="fab-actions" [ngClass]="{'fabActionsHide':!FabToggle,'fabActionsShow':FabToggle}">
    <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='reload()'>
      <md-icon svgIcon="refresh"></md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='DF()'>
      <md-icon svgIcon="pdf"></md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary" (click)='SV()'>
      <md-icon svgIcon="csv"></md-icon>
    </button>
    <button  md-mini-fab class="md-fab md-raised md-primary (click)="addModal.show()">
      <md-icon style="color:white;">add</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.fab-actions button {
     margin-top: 8px;
    }

    #right-side button {
    background-color: #00bcd4 !important;
    height: 55px;
    width: 55px;
    font-size: 32px;
    }

    #right-side button:hover,
    #right-side button:focus {
    background-color: #000 !important;
    }

    .fab-actions button md-icon {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    }

    .fabActionsShow {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.1ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.1ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 0.1ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -o-transition: all 0.1ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 0.1ms cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    }

    .fabActionsHide {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 2.0s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -o-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    -ms-transition: all 1.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.5, 0.75, 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this in CSS file for #right-side button

```
#right-side button {
background-color: #00bcd4 !important;
height: 55px;
width: 55px;
font-size: 32px;
transition: transform ease-out 0.5s;
transition-duration: 0.5s;
```

}

in HTML define id for your FAB buttons I have defined as menu1,menu2,menu3,menu4 and then add these in CSS

```
    .fabActionsHide #menu1 {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.25, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -30px, 0px);
}

.fabActionsHide #menu2 {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.1, 0.25, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -60px, 0px);
}

.fabActionsHide #menu3 {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 1, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -120px, 0px);
}

.fabActionsHide #menu4 {
    animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1);
    transform: translate3d(0px, -180px, 0px);
}
```

Comment: ya i wil share.

Comment: you need the same scaling animation as you have given in the link.

Comment: Ya i need the same way

Comment: Thanks the buttons are showing and hididng bit slow.. Rest il work